# EventHubTrigger function app, pass event hub name and consumer group name dynamically to event hub attribute

Tags: c#-4.0, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-function-app

We know the Connection string for event hub can be used from local.setting.json file. So for the same function app in different environments, I can add the event hub connection string setting in Application settings in the azure portal.

As the EventHubTrigger function app also expects event name and consumer group(optional) as attributes parameters, I was wondering how the event hub name and consumer group can be used from app settings?

```
  public static void EventHubTriggerFunc([EventHubTrigger("myeventhubname", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting", ConsumerGroup = "myconsumergroupname")] EventData myEventHubMessage, DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc, Int64 sequenceNumber, string offset, ILogger log)
 {
   // Here EventHubConnectionAppSetting is specified in local.setting.json file
   //myeventhubname & myconsumergroupname are hard coded string
 }
```

> local.settings.Json

```
   {
    "IsEncrypted": false,
   "Values": {
   "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
   "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
   "EventHubConnectionAppSetting": "Endpoint=.....",
   "EventHubConsumerGroup": "myconsumergroup"
  }
   }
```

Answer (score 18):

```
([EventHubTrigger("%myeventhubname%", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting", ConsumerGroup = "%myconsumergroupname%")]
```

Comment: Thank God for this answer! Oh, and thank YOU, too! ;)

Comment: That's cool, thanks !
I would just add it is called `Azure Functions binding expression patterns`
And add link to source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns

Answer (score 1):

Tried @Roman Kiss answer, and applied it to Python Azure Functions and it works.

In `function.json`:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "events",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "%EVENT_HUB_NAME%",
      "connection": "EVENT_HUB_CONN_STR",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default",
      "dataType": "binary"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that connection string does not need `%`

In `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "Values": {
    ...
    "EVENT_HUB_NAME": "<actual name of event hub>",
    "EVENT_HUB_CONN_STR": "Endpoint=sb://...;SharedAccessKeyName=...;SharedAccessKey=...",
    ...
  },
}
```